Error: "Warning: Errors during XML parse" when running sdkmanager --list on Android SDK
Question Body
I'm encountering an issue when trying to use sdkmanager to list and install packages in the Android SDK on Kali Linux. Whenever I run the command, I receive the following warnings:
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Context
I've installed the Android SDK and extracted it to /opt/android-sdk/. I ensured that the cmdline-tools are in place. However, when I attempt to execute the command:
bash
sdkmanager --list
I receive the XML parse errors, and as a result, I'm unable to install some packages.
What I've Tried
I checked the Java version and confirmed I have OpenJDK 23 installed:
bash
Copiar código
java -version
I configured the JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly.
I added the following path to my PATH variable in .bashrc:
bash
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/
I verified that the command is executed in a terminal that recognizes the changes to the PATH.
Question
What could be causing these XML parse errors when using sdkmanager? Are there specific configurations or steps I need to follow to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated!
Additional Information
Kali Linux version: Most recent stable version
Android SDK version: Most recent stable version
Java version: OpenJDK 23
Thank you for your assistance!

Don't mean to nitpick, but saying "Most recent stable version" when talking about software doesn't really help anyone that comes to this thread e.g. 10 years in the future...ATM this isn't really an issue since your question was only posted a few months ago, but yeah...good questions on SO should always consider future readers ;-)

I found that by wrapping the packages I want to install in "quotes" the issue is resolved. For example, instead of:

sdkmanager --install build-tools;35.0.0

try:

sdkmanager --install "build-tools;35.0.0"

